# Как в Android создать набор полей с автопереходом между ними?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, focus

Как в Android (2.3+) cоздать список полей, например, для ввода IP-адреса
<xxx>.<xxx>.<xxx>.<xxx> ? Причем, чтобы пользователь активировал поле и просто набивал цифры, например 010001225001 -> 10.001.225.001.
Если делать строковое поле  ввода, то в нем не получается  автоматический перескок через точки.  Начальное содержимое строкового поля не сохраняется, так что подсказка вида xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx будет стерта вводом и все. 
Если делать набор полей с цифрами - то по активации первого поля (010) оно так и остается активированным и для перехода во второе поле (001) надо еще раз кликать на следующее поле (фокус остается на первом поле, а надо бы, чтобы он перескочил на второе поле).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Мне кажется, что Вам нужно создать список Ваших EditText. Затем на каждый EditText повесить по TextWatcher'у и при достижении в каждом из них 3-х цифр переводить фокус на следующий EditText. Так, моя догадка была верна. Вот Вам работающий код. Извините, написан чуть некрасиво, но я проверил - всё работает так, как Вы описали в вопросе.
Это самый простой xml с 4-мя EditText.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="3"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="3" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="3"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="3" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="3"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="3" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="3"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

А это уже само Activity, в котором происходит нужная работа.

```
package com.blogspot.leved_notes.answerhashcode;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher {

int current;
ArrayList<EditText> array;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    current = 0;
    array = new ArrayList<EditText>(4);

    EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText edit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText edit3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    EditText edit4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    edit1.addTextChangedListener(this);
    edit2.addTextChangedListener(this);
    edit3.addTextChangedListener(this);
    edit4.addTextChangedListener(this);

    array.add(0, edit1);
    array.add(1, edit2);
    array.add(2, edit3);
    array.add(3, edit4);
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (s.length() == 3) {
        current++;
        if (current < 4) {
            array.get(current).requestFocus();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

На stackoverlow.com есть [множество](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661915/what-androidinputtype-should-i-use-for-entering-an-ip-address) ответов на этот вопрос.
[Наиболее простой](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26290844/872294) (но с низким рейтингом):
`<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ip_address"
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    android:digits="0123456789."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Задача аналогична форматированию номера телефона.

Можно подписаться на `TextChangedListener` и модифицировать поле ввода. [Здесь можно прочитать подробнее](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278382/textchangedlistener-differences-between-ontextchanged-beforetextchanged-and-a).

Также для красоты можно переопределить поведение подсказки `edittext`, чтобы при вводе символов было видно серым текстом формат.